# Android SpeechRecognizer using RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE param doesn't work

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm trying to force `SpeechRecognizer` to work offline with `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE` for better performance.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all, and Android Studio shows in Logcat the following:

```
2578-2578/? I/A: RecognitionService#onStartListening
2578-2578/? I/A: Trigger application overridden to com.apollo.voice
2578-2578/? I/A: Using language specified in RecognizerIntent: pt-BR
2578-2578/? I/A: Trigger application overridden to com.apollo.voice
2578-2578/? E/A: Error parsing intent: EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE parameter is deprecated.
```

If there's no solution, is there any workaround?

Obs.: When I put the smartphone in airplane mode, `SpeechRecognizer` works very fast compared to online. But I don't have internet access that way.